# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. Getting data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

guys! I'm using ReactJS to create a small website. Since I added the following code it starts showing an error: **Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Code:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { motion, useAnimation } from 'framer-motion';
import './css/App.min.css';
import config from './config';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="myskills">
      <Skills skillType="coding" />
    </div>
  );
}

function Skills(props){
  const skillType = props.skillType;
  const result = config.skills.filter(skill => skill.cat == skillType);
  console.log(result);
  result.map((skill, index) => (
    <div className="singleSkill" key={index}>
      {skill.name} Level: {skill.level}
    </div>
  ));
  return (<div>{result}</div>);
}
```

**config.json**

```json
{
  "skills": [
    {
      "name": "HTML",
      "level": 5,
      "cat": "coding"
    },
    {
      "name": "CSS",
      "level": 5,
      "cat": "coding"
    },
    {
      "name": "PHP",
      "level": 4,
      "cat": "coding"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas what's the problem?

Comment: you would need to save the output of the map in a variable. currently, you are just ignoring the output

Comment: You are returning the result, where as you should store the value of map in an new array and return that.
Map doesn't change the actual array instead returns a new array
Or you could directly use {JSON.stringify(result)} if you just want to check whether you are getting the data or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return statement in your `Skills` component is basically just this:

```
return (config.skills.filter(skill => skill.cat == skillType));
```

hence the "Objects are not valid as a React child" error.

Since `result.map` doesn't modify the original array, a better solution might look something like this:

```
function Skills(props) {
  const skillType = props.skillType;
  const result = config.skills.filter(skill => skill.cat == skillType);
  return (
    <div>
      {result.map((skill, index) => (
        <div className="singleSkill" key={index}>
          {skill.name} Level: {skill.level}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```